# Operating first time my 42082 set

Tags: technic

I completed building the [42082 Rough Terrain Crane](https://brickset.com/sets/42082-1/Rough-Terrain-Crane) set and just found out that the boom does not work and the rear spread legs do not fold out, just the front ones.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kobi. Thanks for visiting Bricks.SE. Typically with Technic sets, if certain features don’t work, you have made a mistake somewhere in your build, either mounting something in reverse or not in the right place, or by mixing up some parts (or even skipping a part). Try going back through the instructions and check on your build to see if all pieces are in the right place (might require a partial teardown of the set). For us to help you, you would need to take a few pictures and attach them to your question. Good luck!

Comment: Adding to Phil's comment, when it comes to mechanical functions not working, videos are sometimes way more useful than pictures, as they contain important clues (jitter, seeing some parts start to move and get stuck, hearing the noise of misaligned gears or motors struggling, etc.)

Comment: On a standalone note, try following the transmission of torque from the motor(s) through the gears, axles and other parts, until you get to one of the following: - the parts that should be moving (boom or legs), - a dead-end, meaning a piece is missing, - a locked piece (wrong piece placed or the right part is at the wrong place). After you have done so, be sure to come back and share your findings, even if you have managed to solve it on your own, as your solution could be helping other future builders!